# use a specific from address to send an Outlook._MailItem email

Tags: outlook, mailitem

Is there any way we can override the from email address while programatically (using c#) send an Outlook._MailItem email? Below is the non-working code.

```
        foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts)
        {
            if (account.SmtpAddress == "me@evilEmpire.com")
            {
                olkMail1.SendUsingAccount = account;

                Outlook.AddressEntry newEntry = null; //Not working.
                newEntry.Address = "miniMe@evilEmpire.com";

                olkMail1.Sender = newEntry;

                ((Outlook._MailItem)olkMail1).Send();

                break;
            }
        }
```